# Create file with broadfilesystemaccess set - std::ifstream works, std::ofstream gets access denied in same folder

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, c++-winrt

I cannot create a file using c++/winrt, uwp and std::ofstream. I receive a 0x0000005 (access denied) when calling GetLastError(). I can successfully read in a file using std::ifstream from the same folder. 
I am running windows10 ver1903 x64, vs2017 ver15.9.13

I have added the broadFileSystemAccess to the package manifest and enabled file system access for the entire system and for the application itself. I do get a warning regarding the use of rescap:Capability in the manifest but the application compiles and hasn't restricted others (from what I read) from successfully accessing the file system.

From the package manifest:

```xml
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot rescap" >
```

This is the Capabilities section:

```xml
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

This is my call to ofstream with strOutputFileName containing a filename of a file I want to create in the Debug\UWPAA\AppX directory of the (UWPAA) application (I have tried other directories as well):

```cpp
std::ofstream ofBinary;
ofBinary.open(strOutputFileName, ios::out);
```

I would have expected the application to be able to create the file especially since I am able to open files in file system with std::ifstream but instead I am getting "access denied".

Any ideas? This has been driving me crazy...

Comment: They should work fine if you aim them at a location the app has write access to (i.e. locations in the ApplicationData folders).So you can try to use the **localFolder** directory.

Comment: Thanks faywang. Indeed, in the localFolder I can read and write. In the AppX directory I was only able to read (so I guess it is read only) but I don't have access to the file system as should be defined by broadFileSystemAccess. I tried both reading and writing in directories in the file system and received "access denied". So I guess my problem actually lies with the fact that broadFileSystemAccess isn't working... 

As I mentioned above the application is listed and file system access settings for the application and in general are turned on. 

Any Ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: From the comment below,you seem to find the answer.That would be helpful for other communities who meet the same problem.So you can post the answer directly if you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read through the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). Specifically, the app install location is read-only. Note also that the application can put local & roaming data in separate locations based on application needs.

Comment: Yes thanks Ben,I now understand that I can't use stl to access files outside of the application directories with broadFileSystemAccess, only through the brokered APIs provided by winRT. I found a thread describing the problem and a partial work around here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/a69503ba-e0f6-4060-a43e-d273785a18a0/uwpcbroadfilesystemaccess-and-win32-api-for-uwp?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate regarding the partial workaround, it is now possible (from version 1803 on-wards) to use CreatFileFromApp which allows you to create the file anywhere the application has brokered access (in the case of broadFileSystemAccess, to the entire file system). Once the file is created you can access the HANDLE of the file through StorageFile's IStorageItemHandleAccess. 
In this manner it is now possible to use the HANDLE with Win32 interface, the only problem is (which is why I call it a partial workaround), I haven't found a way to provide the handle to std::ofstream, so I'm stuck using the win32 api for file access.